# JavaScript/jQuery JSON Array Issue - Values as Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm pulling data from a JSON file:

```
[
{
    "video": "video/preroll"
},
{
    "video": "video/areyoupopular"
},
{
    "video": "video/destinationearth"
}]
```

I've tried a console.log at various stages and don't have a problem until I get to the stage below. I need the values for each video in the JSON string and put them into an array labeled playlist. The code I'm using is:

```
$(function() {
    var playlist = [];

    var url = "http://localhost/class_files2/week7.1/video-data.json";

    $.get(url, function(data) {
       // console.log(data); at this point returns the JSON string as expected.
       for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
           playlist.push(data[i].video);
       } 
        console.log(playlist);
    });
});
```

The array is showing up, but with several undefined values (see screenshot). 
[array error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQs3i.png)

I should be getting the video values into the playlist array. I've gotten help from someone else who is having the values pushed into the playlist array as expected using my same files.

If I put the console.log before the push into the array, I get the JSON string, but it's run through 156 times (see screenshot).
[array 156](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONND4.png)

I've tried creating new files and retyping (not copying and pasting). I've trying using the full AJAX GET method. I'm certain it's something with my for statement, but everything seems right. I had reached out for help with someone else, but they are getting the array as expected (second screenshot) without an issue. 
I'm running XAMPP for OS X 1.8.3-4
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
OSX El Capitan 10.11.4
Same error occurs in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

What could possibly be the issue? It's especially odd since the same files on someone else computer seem to work, unless there's another variable that's not being accounted for.

Comment: your code looks fine. perhaps your data file is corrupted

Comment: can you tell me the type of `data`. Added a line before for loop `console.log(typeof(data));`, I doubt, it is a json string

Comment: Try to insert the `var playlist = [];` declaration inside the asynchronous `get` function and return it as a result. You are running an asynchronous function within a synchronous function where the playlist was defined.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their suggestions. I've redownloaded the json file. I've also sent the complete zipped file to another person, including the json file, and they are seeing the correct array. So, I don't think the file is corrupted.

Comment: When I move var playlist = []; into the function, I still get an array with 156 values of undefined.

Comment: Using console.log(typeof(data)); "String" is returned

Comment: Here      // console.log(data); at this point returns the JSON string as expected.

in this piece of code you are getting data as a JSON string, first you need to parse that JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using for loop with list/arrays. Use forEach loop.

Try This.

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
   // console.log(data); at this point returns the JSON string as expected.
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   data.forEach(function(item) {
       playlist.push(item.video);
   });
    console.log(playlist);
});
```

Comment: I like this as an option but am getting an error of 
TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
any idea of why this wold be?

Comment: then it is sure that, data is not an array, it is a json string. You need to parse it first. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) also has another argument where you can specify the type of data you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks! That did it!